# Flattening of Nested dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a multi level nested dataframe something like the below:

```
DataFrame[date_time: timestamp, filename: string, label: string, description: string, 
feature_set: array<struct<direction:string,tStart:double,tEnd:double, 
features:array<struct<field1:string,field2:string,field3:string,field4:string>>>>]
```

and its values are:

```
[[datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 24, 7, 51, 54), 'filename1', 'label1', 'description of file 1', [['east', 78.23018987, 79.23010199, [['fld_val11', 'fld_val12', 'fld_Val13', 'fld_Val14']]], ['west', 78.23018987, 79.23010199, [['fld_val21', 'fld_val22', 'fld_val23', 'fld_val24']]], ['south', 78.23018987, 79.23010199, [['fld_val31', 'fld_val32', 'fld_val33', 'fld_val34']]]


root
 |-- date_time: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- filename: string (nullable = true)
 |-- label: string (nullable = true)
 |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- feature_set: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- direction: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- tStart: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- tEnd: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- features: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- field1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- field2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- field3: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- field4:string (nullable = true)
```

I am trying to flatten it in such a way that it should look like below:

```
-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|          date_time|            filename|               label|         description| feature_set_direction| feature_set_tStart| feature_set_tEnd| feature_set_features_Field1| feature_set_features_Field2| feature_set_features_Field3| feature_set_features_Field4| 
+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+

|2022-08-24 13:47:47|filename1|label1| description of file 1|east| 78.230189787|79.23010199| fld_val11| fld_val12| fld_Val13| fld_Val14|

+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
root
 |-- date_time: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- filename: string (nullable = true)
 |-- label: string (nullable = true)
 |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- feature_set: array (nullable = true)
 |-- feature_set_element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |-- feature_set_element_direction: string (nullable = true)
 |-- feature_set_element_tStart: double (nullable = true)
 |-- feature_set_element_tEnd: double (nullable = true)
 |-- feature_set_element_features: array (nullable = true)
 |-- feature_set_element_features_element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |-- feature_set_element_features_element_field1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- feature_set_element_features_element_field2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- feature_set_element_features_element_field3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- feature_set_element_features_element_field4:string (nullable = true)
```

I tried to flatten it with the help of the below code, but its throwing error:

```
flat_df = df.select("date_time", "filename", "label", "description", "feature_set.*")
```

> AnalysisException: Can only star expand struct data types. Attribute:
> `ArrayBuffer(feature_set)`.

I also tried with couple of other methods like val, but quite unsuccessful.

```
val df2 = df.select(col("date_time"),
                                    col("filename"),
                                    col("label"),
                                    col("description"),
                                    col("feature_set"))
```

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax (, line 1)   File :1
> val df2 = df.select(col("date_time")

Could anyone please suggest how to proceed with?

Thank you.

Comment: When you have a column of type array (like feature_set: array), then you have to explode it before doing the "feature_set.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're working with arrays, you can't simply select the subcolumns: you'll need to use `explode` first.

This code block is just to recreate your data (You shouldn't have to do this):

```py
import datetime
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([
    StructField("date_time", TimestampType(), True),
    StructField("filename", StringType(), True),
    StructField("label", StringType(), True),
    StructField("description", StringType(), True),
    StructField("feature_set",
        ArrayType(
            StructType([
                StructField("direction", StringType(), True),
                StructField("tStart", DoubleType(), True),
                StructField("tEnd", DoubleType(), True),
                StructField("features",
                    ArrayType(
                        StructType([
                            StructField("field1", StringType(), True),
                            StructField("field2", StringType(), True),
                            StructField("field3", StringType(), True),
                            StructField("field4", StringType(), True),
                        ])
                    ), True),
            ])
        )
    )
])

data = [ ( datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 24, 7, 51, 54), 'filename1', 'label1', 'description of file 1', [ ( 'east', 78.23018987, 79.23010199, [ ( 'fld_val11', 'fld_val12', 'fld_Val13', 'fld_Val14') ]), ( 'west', 78.23018987, 79.23010199, [ ( 'fld_val21', 'fld_val22', 'fld_val23', 'fld_val24') ]), ( 'south', 78.23018987, 79.23010199, [ ( 'fld_val31', 'fld_val32', 'fld_val33', 'fld_val34') ]) ]) ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
```

Now that we have the data, we need to use a combination of `select` and `explode` to get the schema we want:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

flat_df = df \
  .withColumn("feature_set", F.explode("feature_set")) \
  .select("date_time", "filename", "label", "description", "feature_set.*") \
  .withColumn("features", F.explode("features")) \
  .select("date_time", "filename", "label", "description", "direction", "tStart", "tEnd", "features.*")
```

So as you see, we're `explode`ing each array column and unwrapping them afterwards. Like this, you're telling Spark to make a row in the resulting dataframe for each element in the arrays you have.

The output schema won't exactly be the same as what you're asking (the `feature_set` array is not there anymore e.g.) but this makes a more compact version without any data duplication. The resulting schema and dataframe look like this:

```
>>> flat_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- date_time: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- filename: string (nullable = true)
 |-- label: string (nullable = true)
 |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- direction: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tStart: double (nullable = true)
 |-- tEnd: double (nullable = true)
 |-- field1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- field2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- field3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- field4: string (nullable = true)

>>> flat_df.show()
+-------------------+---------+------+--------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|          date_time| filename| label|         description|direction|     tStart|       tEnd|   field1|   field2|   field3|   field4|
+-------------------+---------+------+--------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|2022-08-24 07:51:54|filename1|label1|description of fi...|     east|78.23018987|79.23010199|fld_val11|fld_val12|fld_Val13|fld_Val14|
|2022-08-24 07:51:54|filename1|label1|description of fi...|     west|78.23018987|79.23010199|fld_val21|fld_val22|fld_val23|fld_val24|
|2022-08-24 07:51:54|filename1|label1|description of fi...|    south|78.23018987|79.23010199|fld_val31|fld_val32|fld_val33|fld_val34|
+-------------------+---------+------+--------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. While it is expanding the last level of values very nicely (Field1, Field2, Field3, field4), it is ignoring the higher levels (tStart, tEnd, Filename, Labels etc). Not sure whether I made any mistake. But if you have any thoughts please let me know

Comment: +------+----------------+-----+--------+---------+-------------------+-------+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------------+--------------------+
|Field1|          Field2| Field3|Field4|

Comment: Can you edit your question and add some example input data? It can be in json/csv/whatever format you're using. Then I'll make sure to give you a fully workable solution :)

Comment: I tried to update. Please let me know if this is fine.

Comment: I've adapted my answer, let me know if that's what you're looking for!